# jQuery programming to store values in sqlite database

Tags: jquery

I am trying to insert registration form values into sqlite database using jQuery, dont know where i am going wrong, can anybody help me to resolve this?

```
var db=openDatabase("foo4","1.0","my simple database","200000");
            db.transaction(function (tx) 
                {   
                    if ($("#gender").attr("checked", "true"))
                    {
                        var $g="male";
                    }
                    else
                    var $g="female";
                    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo4 (rno INTEGER, name TEXT, email TEXT, phone INTEGER, age INTEGER, address TEXT, password TEXT, gender TEXT)');
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO foo4 VALUES('+$("#rno").val()+',"'+
                        $("#name").val()+'","'+$(#"email").val()+'",'+$(#"pno").val()+','+
                        $(#"age").val()+',"'+$(#"address").val()+'","'+$(#"pwd").val()+'","'+$("#g").val()+'")');
                    alert("success");
                    window.open("home.html","_self");        
                });
        }
 else
    window.alert(error);
```

Iam getting the error as at

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO foo4 VALUES(' + $("#rno").val() + ',"' + $("#name").val() + '","' + $(#"email").val() + '",' + $(#"pno").val() + ',' + $(#"age").val() + ',"' + $(#"address").val() + '","' + $(#"pwd").val() + '","' + $("#g").val() + '")');

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

Comment: You have some `$(#"pwd")` that should be `$("#pwd")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO foo4 VALUES('+$("#rno").val()+',"'+
                    $("#name").val()+'","'+$("#email").val()+'",'+$("#pno").val()+','+
                    $("#age").val()+',"'+$("#address").val()+'","'+$("#pwd").val()+'","'+$("#g").val()+'")')
```